# Are these structures real petals?

Tags: botany, flowers

I don't know the name of the plant. It's a common house plant in Bangladesh. What interests me about its flower is the colorful leaflike structure that probably functions as a petal. What is this structure homologous to? Petal, sepal, bract or leaf?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plant looks like something in the genus [*Bougainvillea*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bougainvillea). These plants are native to South America, but found as introduced ornamentals in many places.

The colored petal-like organs are bracts (see the Wikipedia link above). The entire structure is an inflorescence with the flower buds growing out from the surface of the colored bracts — you should eventually see those flowers open and you could then dissect them confirm that the usual flower structures are present.

This is a well labeled diagram:
[image: from: https://benkolstad.net/?p=7010]